# Unused template parameter on Rust struct

Tags: generics, rust

I have this code (simplified):

```
pub struct MessageSender<T: prost::Message> {
    send_channel: crossbeam::Sender<Vec<u8>>,
}

impl<T> MessageSender<T> where T: prost::Message {
    pub fn send(&self, output: &T) {
        let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(output.encoded_len());
        output.encode(&mut buf).unwrap();
        self.send_channel.send(buf).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Hopefully the intent is clear - I want a `struct` that can send a specific `struct` that implements `prost::Message`, but I only actually need that template parameter for the `send()` function. I can fix this by adding `_marker: PhantomData<T>` to the `struct`.

Is that the right thing to do here? Also why is it necessary? Seems a bit annoying because then I have to initialise that marker everywhere I create one of these structs.

Comment: Why don't you make the `send` method generic, instead?

Comment: Because I pass the struct to another function and I don't want that function to be able to send *any* `prost::Message`.

Comment: Well, in this case, you must use a `PhantomData`.

Comment: `PhantomData<T>` gives the wrong variance for send-like semantics; you want `PhantomData<fn(T)>`.

Comment: @trentcl: Can you explain a bit more for a noob? (Maybe in an answer)